# How to ask cloudcustodian report only for non complient resources

Tags: cloudcustodian

We are trying to use cloudcustodian for infrastructure audit and generate csv report for resources which does not match tagging policy

Config example:

```
vars:
  tag-filters: &tag-compliance-filters
      - "tag.team_name": absent
      - "tag.product_name": absent
      - "tag.application_name": absent
      - "tag.service_name": absent
      - "tag.group": absent


policies:
- name: tag-compliance-rds
  resource: aws.rds
  description: |
    Detect resources which does not meet tags compliance 
  filters: 
      - and: *tag-compliance-filters
```

But in CSV report I see all resources (even resources that match this policy). c7n-org utility used. So, the question is how to filter only noncomplient resources which do not have at least one of these tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this post a very old. Still answering

**You will have to use OR in the filters.**

```
vars:
  tag-filters: &tag-compliance-filters
      - "tag.team_name": absent
      - "tag.product_name": absent
      - "tag.application_name": absent
      - "tag.service_name": absent
      - "tag.group": absent


policies:
- name: tag-compliance-rds
  resource: aws.rds
  description: |
    Detect resources which does not meet tags compliance 
  filters: 
      - or: *tag-compliance-filters
```